# How can I Fourier phase scramble a grayscale JPEG image in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I need to Fourier phase scramble a whole load of JPEG images in Matlab.

Using the following script I am able to phase scramble colour images, but when I try it on grayscale it does not work. I have installed the image processing in Matlab already.

Any advice on how to modify code so that it phase scrambles grayscale would be much appreciated, as I have tried reducing ImSize from 3 to 2, and reducing (:,:,layer) to (:,layer) - but still no joy!

Thanks in advance,

Maria

```
Im = mat2gray(double(imread('c:\nick\matlab\randomphase\Bear.jpg')));
%read and rescale (0-1) image

ImSize = size(Im);

RandomPhase = angle(fft2(rand(ImSize(1), ImSize(2))));
%generate random phase structure

for layer = 1:ImSize(3)
    ImFourier(:,:,layer) = fft2(Im(:,:,layer));       
%Fast-Fourier transform
    Amp(:,:,layer) = abs(ImFourier(:,:,layer));       
%amplitude spectrum
    Phase(:,:,layer) = angle(ImFourier(:,:,layer));   
%phase spectrum
    Phase(:,:,layer) = Phase(:,:,layer) + RandomPhase;
%add random phase to original phase
    ImScrambled(:,:,layer) = ifft2(Amp(:,:,layer).*exp(sqrt(-1)*(Phase(:,:,layer))));   
%combine Amp and Phase then perform inverse Fourier
end

ImScrambled = real(ImScrambled); %get rid of imaginery part in image (due to rounding error)
imwrite(ImScrambled,'BearScrambled.jpg','jpg');

imshow(ImScrambled)
```

Comment: I had to change the `ImSize(3)` to `size(Im,3)` and the code seems to be running, but I am not sure what output you expect.

Comment: It's working now - output is gray - I must have changed something else before as was coming out green! Thanks so much for your help! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are using `ImSize = size(Im);` and `ImSize(3)`, the problem is for grayscale images `ImSize` has only two elements because it's a 2d matrix.

Instead use `size(Im,3)` which returns 1, as matlab always assumes additional singleton dimensions. For the same reason, your further code is already compartible to grayscale images, as `Im(:,:,layer)` with `layer=1` returns the full image, which is what you want in this case.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying :)